# Search data between two timestamp in oracle

Tags: date, oracle11g, between

I am trying to search data between two dates, but it retrieving old data where not in  the range i gave? kindly advice me how to re-write the below query logic

```
select *
from Users
where TO_CHAR(Users.lastloggedindate,'dd-MON-yy HH.MI.SS') between '17-JAN-17 07.16.55' and
                                                                   '18-JAN-17 09.20.22';
```

Comment: What is the column type of `lastloggedindate` ?

Comment: Output:                                                                                             17-MAY-12 11.41.55
18-JAN-17 19.19.08
17-OCT-14 16.12.41
18-JAN-17 20.21.15
17-SEP-08 10.16.53
17-JUL-09 12.27.57
18-FEB-13 08.00.48
18-APR-12 13.30.26
18-APR-12 13.32.28
17-NOV-15 15.41.07
17-JAN-17 09.44.25
17-JAN-17 21.15.28
18-APR-13 13.36.59
18-JAN-17 20.29.28

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `to_date()` instead of `to_char()`, to convert the two points of the range into dates against which your logged in date can be compared:

```
select *
from Users
where Users.lastloggedindate between to_date('2017-17-01 07:16:55', 'YYYY-DD-MM HH24:MI:SS') and
                                     to_date('2017-18-01 09:20:22', 'YYYY-DD-MM HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: @Muthusankar To add to Tim's answer, the reason why your original query wasn't working as expected is because you were comparing strings and not dates. A string of '17-JAN-17 07.16.55' is going to be greater than a string of '16-JAN-10 06.31.13' because the first character that's different is the second character and 7 is greater than 6. You could get around this by comparing the strings in a 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' format, but if you're comparing two things that are DATEs, why not let Oracle know that by comparing them as DATEs (which is exactly what Tim's answer does) rather than strings.

Comment: @Boneist Now i understand clearly, Thanks for the clear explanation.